# How to change animation position in Off-Canvas Menu Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm working with [OffCanvasMenuEffects](https://github.com/codrops/OffCanvasMenuEffects) and i'm using wave menu effect. You can see this menu in following:

```css
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}[hidden]{display:none;}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}body{margin:0;}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;}a:active,a:hover{outline:0;}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0;}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}b,strong{font-weight:bold;}dfn{font-style:italic;}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0;}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000;}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em;}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}q{quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";}small{font-size:80%;}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline;}sup{top:-0.5em;}sub{bottom:-0.25em;}img{border:0;}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden;}figure{margin:0;}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;}legend{border:0;padding:0;}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}button,input{line-height:normal;}button,select{text-transform:none;}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default;}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}

html, 
body, 
.container, 
.content-wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.container {
 background: #373a47;
}

.menu-wrap a {
 color: #b8b7ad;
}

.menu-wrap a:hover,
.menu-wrap a:focus {
 color: #c94e50;
}

.content-wrap {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 background: #b4bad2;
}

.content::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 content: '';
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0s 0.4s;
}

/* Menu Button */
.menu-button {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 0;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.25em;
 border: none;
 text-indent: 2.5em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: transparent;
 background: transparent;
}

.menu-button::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0.5em;
 right: 0.5em;
 bottom: 0.5em;
 left: 0.5em;
 background: linear-gradient(#373a47 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #373a47 40%, #373a47 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #373a47 80%);
 content: '';
}

.menu-button:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-button {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1em;
 top: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: 16px;
 border: none;
 z-index: 1001;
 background: transparent;
 color: transparent;
}

.close-button::before,
.close-button::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 background: #888;
}

.close-button::before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-button::after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Menu */
.menu-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1001;
 width: 100%;
 height: 160px;
 font-size: 1.15em;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.menu {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 text-align: center; 
 top: 50%;
 padding: 0 1.5em;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
}

.icon-list a,
.close-button {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,200px,0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
}

.icon-list a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.8em;
}

.icon-list a i {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-list a span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Morph Shape */
.morph-shape {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 width: calc(100% + 400px);
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 fill: #373a47;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-400px,0,0);
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .menu-wrap,
.show-menu .icon-list a,
.show-menu .close-button,
.show-menu .morph-shape,
.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.show-menu .menu-wrap,
.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a,
.show-menu .close-button,
.show-menu .content::before {
 opacity: 1;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
 transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
 transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.show-menu .close-button {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="icon-list">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>Favorites</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Alerts</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Messages</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>Comments</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Analytics</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>Reading List</span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
    <div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape" data-morph-open="M0,100h1000V0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0C583,0,610.924,0,498,0C387,0,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,0,0,0V100z">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M0,100h1000l0,0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0c-193,0-170.235-1.256-278-35C399,34,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,100,0,100L0,100z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
  
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/main3.js"></script>
```

Currently the Menu opens from bottom to top.

My question is how is it possible to change the position of how the off canvas menu loads, default is bottom to top with wave effect convert to top to bottom, like this website: https://afriendofmine.nl

How can this be achieved?

I was tried to edit the menu but the result not good! I edit `.menu-wrap` class. I replace `bottom: 0;` with `top: 0;` as following:

```
.menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; //edited
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
```

After all, how can I make the menu to **opens from top to bottom**? like this website: https://afriendofmine.nl

```css
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}[hidden]{display:none;}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}body{margin:0;}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;}a:active,a:hover{outline:0;}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0;}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}b,strong{font-weight:bold;}dfn{font-style:italic;}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0;}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000;}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em;}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}q{quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";}small{font-size:80%;}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline;}sup{top:-0.5em;}sub{bottom:-0.25em;}img{border:0;}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden;}figure{margin:0;}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;}legend{border:0;padding:0;}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}button,input{line-height:normal;}button,select{text-transform:none;}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default;}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}

html, 
body, 
.container, 
.content-wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.container {
 background: #373a47;
}

.menu-wrap a {
 color: #b8b7ad;
}

.menu-wrap a:hover,
.menu-wrap a:focus {
 color: #c94e50;
}

.content-wrap {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 background: #b4bad2;
}

.content::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 content: '';
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0s 0.4s;
}

/* Menu Button */
.menu-button {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 0;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.25em;
 border: none;
 text-indent: 2.5em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: transparent;
 background: transparent;
}

.menu-button::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0.5em;
 right: 0.5em;
 bottom: 0.5em;
 left: 0.5em;
 background: linear-gradient(#373a47 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #373a47 40%, #373a47 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #373a47 80%);
 content: '';
}

.menu-button:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-button {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1em;
 top: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: 16px;
 border: none;
 z-index: 1001;
 background: transparent;
 color: transparent;
}

.close-button::before,
.close-button::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 background: #888;
}

.close-button::before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-button::after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Menu */
.menu-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; //edited
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1001;
 width: 100%;
 height: 160px;
 font-size: 1.15em;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,160px,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.menu {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 text-align: center; 
 top: 50%;
 padding: 0 1.5em;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
}

.icon-list a,
.close-button {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,200px,0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
}

.icon-list a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.8em;
}

.icon-list a i {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-list a span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Morph Shape */
.morph-shape {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 width: calc(100% + 400px);
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 fill: #373a47;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-400px,0,0);
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .menu-wrap,
.show-menu .icon-list a,
.show-menu .close-button,
.show-menu .morph-shape,
.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.show-menu .menu-wrap,
.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a,
.show-menu .close-button,
.show-menu .content::before {
 opacity: 1;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
 transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.show-menu .icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
 transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.show-menu .close-button {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.show-menu .content::before {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="icon-list">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>Favorites</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Alerts</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Messages</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>Comments</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Analytics</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>Reading List</span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
    <div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape" data-morph-open="M0,100h1000V0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0C583,0,610.924,0,498,0C387,0,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,0,0,0V100z">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M0,100h1000l0,0c0,0-136.938,0-224,0c-193,0-170.235-1.256-278-35C399,34,395,0,249,0C118,0,0,100,0,100L0,100z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
  
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/js/main3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried any solution? If so, please show us what you have attempted.

Comment: @ItamarG3 I was tried to edit the menu but the result not good! I edited css in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/hz7hfdk9/1/

Comment: That's good that you tried something already (it really is :D), but you should include that in your question.

Comment: @ItamarG3 I done it. :)

Comment: Excellent. However, when you say that the result isn't good, you really should describe **what** isn't good about it. (Your question has potential, I'm just trying to help you refine it)

Comment: create a fiddle it would be easier to edit in fiddle

Comment: @ItamarG3 I edited the question again and more describe. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava Orginal code: https://jsfiddle.net/v19dnbq0/  and my trying: https://jsfiddle.net/hz7hfdk9/1/

Comment: when i set position bottom to top for .menu-wrap it moves up, but path was visible, that you can control by click event on button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v19dnbq0/1/ check this

Comment: you can do something like above fiddle

Comment: @AtalShrivastava that's good. thank you. but i want the animation of menu start from top to bottom. in this demo the animation start from bottom to top. can you edit it?

Comment: change the translate property according to your need in css, you will get the result

Comment: the svg provide in the demo itself has a shape for bottom to top animation, you need to change svg first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need?

```
.morph-shape>svg {
  transform:rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4pmr6ez/1/